# ox_Oracle with database 11g Django problem with view name 'ORDER'

Tags: django, oracle, cx-oracle

In my project I'm using cx_Oracle to connect and receive data from an ORACLE 11g database.

In the database, I have a view 'ORDER' and every time I'm trying to run a query against that view, I get an error

> ORA-01722: invalid number

even with a RAW query. I can't change the view name.

Does anybody have a solution?

- Django ver. 3.2.18
- cx_Oracle ver. 8.3.0
- Instant Client Oracle 21.9

Error occurs even with raw query.

Models in Django are same as view schema.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the query that Django is generating (or the raw query that you are using).

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER` is a reserved word and if you are going to use it as an identifier then you must use a quoted identifier and the correct case.

So, if your view is called `ORDER` (upper-case) then:

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM "ORDER"
```

If your view is called `Order` (title-case) then:

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM "Order"
```

Comment: Was trying all with quoted, duble quoted Upper-case, looses hope to solve problem. thinking to build api in java just to connect to that database.

Comment: Create a view in SQL and query that from the app?